# How can I download In-App purchase fully from sandbox to test

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am wondering how can I download In-App purchase fully from sandbox to test. I know how to do it using the screenshot method to test the the product validity as instructed here. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1329.html

But how do I test it so the in app purchase actually goes to my phone so I can view it, do I actually need to upload the binary?

Comment: when you the the In-App Purchase in the iTunes Connect, it is started to work immediately, if you use it with your real account, you'll pay for it real money, therefore it would be great that you make a test account for testing.

Comment: I did this, and I can go through the whole process of testing except the part where it actually downloads the in-app purchase.

Comment: where do you want to download the content from?

Comment: from my in-app purchases, and I am hosting content with apple.